# Pandas: Groupby and select records which IDs appear x times, where n < x < N

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

In this dataframe I need to select records which UserID-s appear in the dataset x times, where 2 < x < 4:

```
d = {"UserId":[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],"review":["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","k"]}
f = pd.DataFrame(d)

UserId review
0       1      a
1       2      b
2       2      c
3       3      d
4       3      e
5       3      f
6       4      g
7       4      h
8       4      i
9       4      k
```

Selecting records with one condition works:

```
f[f.groupby("UserId")["UserId"].transform('size') > 2]

    UserId  review
3   3   d
4   3   e
5   3   f
6   4   g
7   4   h
8   4   i
9   4   k
```

Can' solve it with number of UserID from interval. This does not work:

```
def check_size(x):
    return 2 < len(x) < 4

f['cnt'] = f.groupby('UserID')['UserID'].transform(check_size('size'))
```

Fails with:

```
...
...   
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
        860                 in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
        861             else:
    --> 862                 raise KeyError(gpr)
        863         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
        864             # Add key to exclusions
    
    KeyError: 'UserID'
```

Comment: also `df.groupby('UserId').filter(lambda x: 2<len(x)<4)`

Comment: you misspelled `"UserId"` that gives error. But also you need to pass `check_size` alone to `transform` as a function so it calls with each group your function, not you. But better way is below.

Comment: I don't see where I misspelled 'UserID"

Comment: @QuangHoang Your answer `df.groupby('UserId').filter(lambda x: 2<len(x)<4)` is the most versatile and thus is the best one. Please post it not as a comment, but as answer and will accept it the one solving the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it. I'm reluctant to post that as an answer since it most likely a duplicate somewhere. Plus, `filter` is a little slower than `transform` then boolean indexing.

Comment: Why do you get a KeyError you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `between`:

```
out = f[f.groupby("UserId")["UserId"].transform('size')
         .between(2, 4, inclusive='neither')]
print(out)

# Output
   UserId review
3       3      d
4       3      e
5       3      f
```

**Update**

> How to add cnt column, so f['cnt'] has count of Id occurrences?

```
out = f.assign(cnt=f.groupby("UserId")["UserId"].transform('size')) \
       .loc[lambda x: x['cnt'].between(2, 4, inclusive='neither')]

# OR

out = f.assign(cnt=f.groupby("UserId")["UserId"].transform('size')) \
       .query("cnt.between(2, 4, inclusive='neither')")
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   UserId review  cnt
3       3      d    3
4       3      e    3
5       3      f    3
```

Comment: Thanks! Two questions: 1) Why do you put expression in `()` brackets: `out = (...)` ? 2) How to add `cnt` column, so `f['cnt']` has count of `Id` occurrences?

Comment: I updated my answer according your comment. Forget about `( )`, that was for writing code on multi lines without using `\\`.

Comment: Second method with `query` failed: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`

Comment: Do you have an old version of Pandas? You probably have to check the `numexpr` package version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `between` for selection between 2 values:

```
f[f.groupby('UserID')['UserID'].transform('size').between(3,5)]
```

Output:

```
   UserID review
3       3      d
4       3      e
5       3      f
6       4      g
7       4      h
8       4      i
9       4      k
```